# Where to find Foundation Framework header files?

Tags: ios

I've tried to check `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/`  but I couldn't even find `Headers` folder inside `Foudnation.framework` as instructed by a book.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroFoundation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it directly at:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/`

or

**Right-click** on `Foundation.framework` in some XCode project, then **Show in Finder** -> **Headers** -> **Voila!**

Comment: I'm on Mac OS 12.3.1 and that path did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Goto -> farmeWork -> choose anyfile .h --> right click how in finder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS 12.3 the Foundation framework is located inside of Xcode.
Here is why mine is located: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/system/library/frameworks/foundation.framework/Headers